# How to display all files with dirent and stat structs in C

Tags: c, io, directory, command-line-arguments, dirent.h

OK, so I'm trying to display all files within a given path-name.
For the first path I enter, all files display correctly. 
However, when I use a sub-directory path as an argument to the function, it only
displays a single executable (there are other files in the sub-directory as a test).
I absolutely cannot figure out why this is happening.
I will post the relevant snippets of code below, any help with this would be greatly 
appreciated.

```
struct dirent *directory;
DIR *pdirectory;
struct stat fileinfo;




pdirectory=opendir(path);
    if (pdirectory==NULL)
    {
            printf("Error: Unable to open directory\n");
            exit(0);
    }
    printf("%s\n",path);
    while ((directory=readdir(pdirectory)) != NULL)
    {

        if (!stat(directory->d_name,&fileinfo))
        {
            if (S_ISREG(fileinfo.st_mode))
            { 
              printf("File Name:              %s\n",directory->d_name); 
              printf("File Size:              %d bytes\n",fileinfo.st_size);
              printf("Last Access:            %s\n",ctime(&fileinfo.st_atime));
            }
            }


    }
        closedir(pdirectory);
   }
```

Comment: Do you have the `<time.h>` included ?

Comment: No, I don't. Would that actually matter?

Comment: `if (pdirectory==NULL) { perror(path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}` ... errors belong on stderr, should include a reason for the failure, and the value passed to exit should be non-zero to indicate that an error occurred.

Comment: Update, I moved the executable into the sub-directory and executed it from there, and now I can see all the files in the sub-directory. So it seems that there is something about the file hierarchy that I do not understand here.

Comment: @user3394907 Yeah it does. This header defines a quantity of *types*, amongst them, the type of the `st_atime` which is `time_t`. You are calling the `ctime` function using a type that has not been declared yet. This is especially dangerous.

Comment: Noted, I've included the correct headers now. Still no closer to solving my original problem though.

Comment: This wasn't meant to solve your issue, but to prevent a potential crash ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the [`stat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) system call is failing because your not providing him  with the *complete*  path to the files located in the opened directory, in the case you are using your program to open a directory other than the current one.

This explains why your code worked only when opening the current directory.

One solution would be to append the path to the directory you're opening to the name of the file contained in the `d_name` member of the `dirent` structure such as :

> /path/to/my/directory/name_of_the_file

or

> path/to/my/directory/name_of_the_file

Comment: How would I give stat the complete path in that case?

Comment: Hmm. I've done something similar. (I originally pass the path name as a command line argument in argv[1].) In my case, I have a folder called Test0, with a sub-directory called Test1. I use the following path /export/home/usr/Test0/Test1 , but that only returns the source file and the a.out executable in the listing.

Comment: Well, are there other regular files in this particular directory other than the source file and the executable ?

Comment: Yes, I have several .txt files in there.

Comment: Ah, I ended up calling chdir(path) before the call to stat(). That fixed it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: All right. I shared my example right here http://codepad.org/mocgJvtX in case you might want to take a look at it.